# No SOA record -- what are the implications?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I was investigating a bunch of spam domains, and none of them have an SOA record.  I have never seen this before -- I didn't even know it was possible.

How can DNS work without an SOA record? If it isn't strictly necessary, what are the implications of omitting it?

I don't particularly want to add links to spam sites but an example domain is "vance miller kitchens uk dot co dot uk".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is in fact a `SOA` record, it's just not where you're expecting it. Let's take a look at the AUTHORITY section...keep in mind that `ns1.nservers.co.uk.` is not in any way affiliated with the `nic.uk.` nameservers, which are authoritative for `co.uk.`.

```
$ dig @ns1.nservers.co.uk. +norecurse +noall +authority vancemillerkitchensuk.co.uk SOA
co.uk.                  3600    IN      SOA     win-k7rk0hedad1. hostmaster. 6 900 600 86400 3600
$ dig @ns1.nservers.co.uk. +norecurse +short co.uk SOA
win-k7rk0hedad1. hostmaster. 6 900 600 86400 3600
```

This betrays their actual configuration: they have a single `co.uk` zone defined. This simplifies their configuration as they only have to maintain one file. The reason you don't get an answer section for the `SOA` request is because that isn't the true top of the zone. Keep in mind that this is a terrible configuration: you should never pretend to be authoritative for domains that you're not. **Don't emulate this**.

`SOA` records are mandatory. You have to stuff *something* in that AUTHORITY section where it is required by RFC if you expect the rest of the internet to play nicely with you. Obviously they aren't *really* authoritative for `co.uk`, but this at least tells other nameservers what the negative TTL should be.

Comment: +1 Mystery solved, thanks! It was partly shrouded by the fact that `host` simply replied `has no SOA record` for this domain, which is sort of understandable, I guess, but clearly wrong (I see now).

Answer (score 5):

`SOA` record at apex of every zone on the child nameservers is mandatory per DNS specification, see [§6.1 of RFC 2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-6.1):

> The authoritative servers for a zone are enumerated in the NS
> records    for the origin of the zone, which, along with a Start of
> Authority    (SOA) record are the mandatory records in every zone.
> Such a server    is authoritative for all resource records in a zone
> that are not in    another zone.

A zone not having a SOA is then not DNS-conforming.
Nameservers will reject it at load time:

```
$ cat example.com 
example.com. 1 NS a.example.
example.com. 1 NS b.example. 

$ named-checkzone example.com example.com 
zone example.com/IN: has 0 SOA records
zone example.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

Maybe you can find a setup where it works, but why risking it?

Besides being mandatory per specification, there are at least 3 items in the SOA record that are needed by clients (all the other items are mostly useful only to the nameservers administrator if its set of nameservers use AXFR/IXFR/DNS Updates to update themselves):

- the `RNAME` is normally the email address of the person responsible for the zone, that you can contact in case of problems; unfortunately nowadays you may not get an answer there or it may not even be a valid existing mailbox anyway, so theoretically useful, in practice not sure
- the `MNAME`, per §4.3 of [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136) is needed for DNS Updates:

> 4.3. If the requestor has reasonable cause to believe that all of a    zone's servers will be equally reachable, then it should arrange to try the primary master server (as given by the SOA MNAME field if matched by some NS NSDNAME) first to avoid unnecessary forwarding inside the slave servers.  (Note that the primary master will in some cases not be reachable by all requestors, due to firewalls or network partitioning.)

- the SOA `MINIMUM` has been redefined over the year to now be the "negative TTL", the amount of time a cache can keep the `NXDOMAIN` reply it got (since an `NXDOMAIN`  reply would return no records in the answer section per definition, there won't be there any TTL to find). See §5 of [RFC 2308](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308):

> Like normal answers negative answers have a time to live (TTL).  As
> there is no record in the answer section to which this TTL can be
> applied, the TTL must be carried by another method.  This is done by
> including the SOA record from the zone in the authority section of
> the reply.  When the authoritative server creates this record its TTL
> is taken from the minimum of the SOA.MINIMUM field and SOA's TTL.
> This TTL decrements in a similar manner to a normal cached answer and
> upon reaching zero (0) indicates the cached negative answer MUST NOT
> be used again.

Proper caching of `NXDOMAIN` replies is important for performances, as outlined in [RFC 8020 "NXDOMAIN: There Really Is Nothing Underneath"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8020): if a name triggers an `NXDOMAIN` reply then the recursive nameserver can, during the time the entry is cached, reply immediately for all names "below" the one queried, as it knows that no name can exist below, per the DNS design of having all names in a tree.

Also, multiple registries test the configuration before allowing to do the delegation. It is not the case for UK, but it is the case for DENIC (.DE) for example. See §2.1.4 in https://www.denic.de/fileadmin/public/documentation/DENIC-23p_EN.pdf that outlines the test on SOA.

Various tools check for it also. See Zonemaster at https://zonemaster.net/ and the explanation of its test on SOA at https://github.com/zonemaster/zonemaster/blob/master/docs/specifications/tests/Delegation-TP/delegation06.md

Answer (score 2):

SOA records pretty much regulate the identity and the update frequency of your DNS servers. If your DNS server is the only authorative DNS server for a domain (Or you control all the authoraties and have a fancy for manual actions), you can omit the SOA record with little to no impact. The only impact might be that some response caching will not happen.

In summary: DNS can work just fine without SOA, SOA just regulates updates to secondary servers, and caching. So it's a really bad idea to not have a SOA record.

Comment: Thanks.  I would still appreciate a bit more detail -- what are the mechanics, which are the parts of the SOA which affect caching? (I assume the caching servers would fall back to fairly conservative TTL values if none are specified, for example?)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, as I haven't had to deal with a SOA record issue that wasn't internal. Have you verified if your SOA test was correct? http://www.kloth.net/services/dig.php allows you to do SOA tests, which you can then point to 8.8.8.8 the google DNS servers to make sure you get a high authority response.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yes, it returns what I expect (nothing for the domain itself, just an SOA for the `co.uk` TLD).

Comment: Only broken nameserver software will allow you to omit a `SOA` record. RFCs *require* one `SOA` record at the top of any zone you are authoritative for.

Comment: "update frequency of your DNS servers" not necessarily. One can as well configure its nameservers set completely out of band, and not relying at all on AXFR/IXFR/DNS Updates, so the values of refresh, expire, etc. in SOA can be arbitrary and meaningless